# Will these dents make this aluminum bike frame unsafe

Tags: frames

Yeah is this small dent fatal?[image: thats the dent it’s on an old cannondale aluminum bike frame.]

Comment: It's difficult to see any dents in the photograph.

Comment: Concur - I see paint scrapes, and a bit of a shadow right below the "e" in the tan area.

Comment: The only possible answers that can be honestly given to a question such as this are "That's definitely dangerous" or "We can't tell". Nobody can declare your bike safe just from a photograph. If you're worried, take it to a bike shop.

Comment: Also, exactly what part of the frame is the photograph showing? This is quite crucial with any frame damage: The parts of the frame are subject to very different kinds of stresses, so a damage that would get me worried on one tube may be a non-issue on another tube.

Comment: Material is also quite important. Steel has some different properties than aluminum, which has totally different properties than carbon. I'm certain that your frame is not the later, but I cannot guess whether it's steel or aluminum.

Answer (score 7):

Noone can answer this authoratively for you.

The common suggestion is for you to include this area of the frame in your monthly maintenance.  Look at it super-close and look for changes over time.

One aid is to take a photo of the area from a cellphone or similar, every month, and look for variation.  Try and keep the lighting and angles the same, and roughly the same time of day.

If the area doesn't change over time, you're probably good.  If it does move and change, stop riding and re-evaluate.